# 3 transitions, pausetime between transitions

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-cycle, jcycle

I want to obtain:

fadeOut 1° image -> fadeIn 1° image -> WAIT 2 SECONDS ->fadeOut 2° image -> fadeIn 2° image -> WAIT 2 SECONDS -> fadeOut 3° image -> fadeIn 3° image -> WAIT 2 SECONDS -> fadeOut 1° image......

Here's the code:

```
<div class="container">
<img width="200" height="200" src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach1.jpg" />
<img width="200" height="200" src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach2.jpg" />
<img width="200" height="200" src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach3.jpg" />
<img width="200" height="200" src="http://static.blogo.it/gamesblog/test-drive-unlimited-2-13/Image00001.jpg" />
<img width="200" height="200" src="http://static.blogo.it/gamesblog/test-drive-unlimited-2-13/Image00002.jpg" />
<img width="200" height="200" src="http://static.blogo.it/gamesblog/test-drive-unlimited-2-13/Image00003.jpg" />
<img width="200" height="200" src="http://static.blogo.it/gamesblog/test-drive-unlimited-2-13/Image00004.jpg" />
<img width="200" height="200" src="http://static.blogo.it/gamesblog/test-drive-unlimited-2-13/Image00005.jpg" />
<img width="200" height="200" src="http://static.blogo.it/gamesblog/test-drive-unlimited-2-13/Image00006.jpg" />
</div>
```

JS:

```
var numberOfGroups = 3;
var arrayOfArray = new Array(numberOfGroups);
for(var i = 0; i < numberOfGroups; i++)
{
    arrayOfArray[i] = new Array();
}
var imagesElements = $('.container').children();
imagesElements.each(function(localIndex){
    //partiziono le immagini in insiemi in base all'ordine in cui le trova in partenza
    arrayOfArray[localIndex % numberOfGroups].push(imagesElements[localIndex]);
});
$('.container').empty();
for(var j = 0; j < arrayOfArray.length; j++)
{
    //crea un nuovo div contenitore contenente le immagini come sono nell'array 2-dimensioni creato
    var newDivContainer = document.createElement('div');
    newDivContainer.setAttribute('id', 'block_'+j);
    for(var k = 0; k < arrayOfArray[j].length; k++)
    {
        newDivContainer.appendChild(arrayOfArray[j][k]);
    }

    $('.container').append(newDivContainer);
}

var newGroups = $('.container').children();
newGroups.each(function(thisIndex){
    $(newGroups[thisIndex]).cycle({
        fx:     'fade',
        delay: 2000,
        speed: 2000,
        //continuous: 1,
        timeout: 2000*numberOfGroups,
        //sync: 0,
        after: function(){
            var x = '#block_'+((thisIndex+1) % numberOfGroups);
            change(x);
            //window.setTimeout(change, 4000, x);
        }
    });
});

function change(what)
{
    jQuery(what).cycle("next");
}
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/linuxatico/5e7X7/

Comment: Please change you comments in code to English.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All you really need to do is set the delay and timeout options appropriately. You can use the index of each group to increase the initial delay option and then subtract out the total animation time from it so your animation starts immediately. Example:

```
var animationDelay = 4000*numberOfGroups - 2000; 
$("#test").cycle({ 
    delay: (4000 * thisIndex) - animationDelay,
    speed: 2000,
    timeout: animationDelay
});
```

Updated the fiddle for you, should be what you're looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/5e7X7/3/